# How to seamlessClone by OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, android

I want to use opencv to seamlessClone on Android,since I have no experience with opencv, the result of debugging is not what I expected (I got the correct result on python, but android is completely wrong). The following is my code, can you give me any clues, or the sample code on android?Thank you.

```
fun compound(originBm: Bitmap, dstBm: Bitmap, maskBm: Bitmap): Bitmap? {
            var matSrc = Mat()
            Utils.bitmapToMat(originBm, matSrc)
            var matDst = Mat()
            Utils.bitmapToMat(dstBm, matDst)
            var matMask = Mat()
            Utils.bitmapToMat(maskBm, matMask)
            cvtColor(matMask, matMask, COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 1)
            var point = Point(matDst.cols() / 2.0, matDst.rows() / 2.0)
            val matBlend = Mat.zeros(matDst.size(), matDst.type())
            seamlessClone(matSrc, matDst, matMask, point, matBlend, MIXED_CLONE)
            var bitmap = createBitmap(matBlend.cols(), matBlend.rows(), ARGB_8888)
            Utils.matToBitmap(matBlend, bitmap)
            return bitmap
        }
```

**The 1024 is the maximum height of the debug window, so the top right corner of the window is not the true width and height.**

OriginBm(1200px*1200px):[image: OriginBm],DstBm(2960*3946):[image: DstBm]
 MaskBm(1200*1200):[image: MaskBm],ResultBm:[image: ResultBm]
 No matter how I modify maskbm and add some area black to it, the resulting graph looks like it's blurred by gaussian.My OpenCV sdk is from:**opencv-4.1.0-android-sdk**.zip.
 I init opencv in my first activity:

```
private val mLoaderCallback = object : BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        override fun onManagerConnected(status: Int) {
            when (status) {
                LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS -> {ToastUtils.showShort("OpenCV loaded successfully")}
                else -> {super.onManagerConnected(status)}
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            println("Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization")
            OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallback)
        } else {
            println("OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!")
            mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var matSrc = Mat()
Utils.bitmapToMat(originBm, matSrc)
cvtColor(matSrc, matSrc, COLOR_RGBA2RGB, 3)//make ARGB bitmap to RGB Mat
dst also need covert.
```

With the code conversion above, the result is now correct.[image]